# Why am I getting 'Future<dynamic>' instead of the return value in the function?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get the return value in my function but the output is 'Instance of Future' instead of the value of school field name in the database

```
         @override
      void initState() {
        userId = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
        publisherSchool =
            getName(widget.postInfo['publisher-Id'], 'school').toString();
        super.initState();
      }

  Future getName(String publisherUid, String fieldname) async {
    DocumentSnapshot publisherSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(publisherUid)
        .get();
    print(publisherSnapshot.get(fieldname));
    return publisherSnapshot.get(fieldname);
  }
```

but whenever i'm printing the publisherSnapshop.get(fieldname) i'm getting the correct value from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it, you can create a `Future` method and call it inside the `initState` like below:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
   initial();
   super.initState();
}

Future<void> initial() async {
  userId = _auth.currentUser!.uid;

  // Remember using `()` to wrap the `await` to get it result
  publisherSchool = (await getName(widget.postInfo['publisher-Id'], 'school')).toString();
}
```

Or you can use `.then` to call it directly inside the `initState`:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  userId = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
  getName(widget.postInfo['publisher-Id'], 'school').then((value) {
     publisherSchool = value.toString();
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: i'm getting an error saying that publisherSchool is not been initialized because i'm using late to declare publisherSchool to global.(i'm trying the .then)

Comment: it says like this "LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'publisherSchool' has not been initialized.)"

Comment: You have to remove `late` and add the `?` like `String? publisherSchool` or `String publisherSchool = ""`, then using the `setState` to apply the changing of `publisherSchool` like `setState(() => publisherSchool = value.toString());`. You can read more about null-safety [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the `getName()` function, specify the return type as `Future<String>`, and then when you call `getName()`, you need to await the result e.g. `publisherSchool = await getName(widget.postInfo['publisher-Id'], 'school').toString();`

Comment: but i'm assigning the variable in the initState() so I can't use await in the initState.

Comment: and also i'm getting an "'await' applied to 'String', which is not a 'Future'." whenever i'm trying to put await in the variable assignment

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not getting the correct response is because whenever you are working with Futures it takes some time to finish and return the results. Meanwhile it is fetching the result you have to make it await so that the program will continue once that future function is complete since await/then is nowhere to be found in your code hence the issues.

To solve this make this change:

**Change**

```
 publisherSchool =
            getName(widget.postInfo['publisher-Id'], 'school').toString();
```

**To**

```
   getName(widget.postInfo['publisher-Id'], 
    'school').then((value){
    publisherSchool=value.toString()});
```

Comment: but i'm assigning the variable in the initState() so I can't use await in the initState.

Comment: and also "'await' applied to 'String', which is not a 'Future'." whenever i'm trying to put await in the variable assignment

Comment: @AdrianAlejo check my answer again and let me know if it works. also don't make it late instead make it nullable for now by String? publisherschool